# express-session different session id inside iframe

Tags: express, iframe, redis, cross-domain, express-session

I am trying to implement some login process inside an iframe on external page and I found out that when I am entering website through iframe the session id of the request is different.

Firefox (correct behaviour):

1. Entering `abc.com` -> `session_id = sometoken1`
2. Entering `dac.com` where is iframe with `abc.com`  -> `session_id = sometoken1`

Chrome (getting different token when entering through iframe)

1. Entering `abc.com` -> `session_id = sometoken1`
2. Entering `dac.com` where is iframe with `abc.com`  -> `session_id = sometoken2`

I was wondering why on Firefox it's working correct and not on Chrome?
Should I add something more to session or cookies setup?:

```
    api.use(session({
      store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
      secret: process.env.REDIS_SESSION_SECRET,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      resave: false,        
    }));
```

I am using Redis and express-session to store token from login proccess.

*EDITED:*

Additionally I found out that cookie property in req is `undefined` when opening iframe in Chrome.

Comment: I think folks here would need to see the framed HTML (both parent and child) to see what settings might be in the frame that Chrome or Firefox would be paying attention to that the other does not support to create the difference.  Or, put another way, you need to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so folks have something to debug and examine.

Comment: I think the issue is that cookie property is missing in req in Chrome but don't know why.

Comment: And, I'm suggesting that there may be some settings in the frame layout that are causing this difference as there are some browser-specific frame-control settings.  And, to help you diagnose that, we'd have to see the actual frame HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in cookie setup, following config is working correct for me:

```
api.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    secret: process.env.REDIS_SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000
    },
}));
```